# How to trigger spunk alert for every stat that appears on my query

Tags: triggers, splunk, alerts, splunk-query, splunk-sum

I currently have a query that results in a couple stats being shown, "Statistics (5)"

[image]

I use this query to get those Stats:

```
index=ms-app  environment=prod AND "*"
| eval uri=replace(mvindex(split('request.uri', "?"), 0), "\/\d+[-+\w]+", "/:n"), methodOverride='request.headers.X-HTTP-Method-Override'
| eval methodOverrideStr = if(isnull(methodOverride) OR methodOverride=="null", "", "(" + methodOverride + ")")
| eval request = 'request.method' + methodOverrideStr + " " + uri + " " + 'response.httpStatusCode'
| stats
median(stats.overallResponseTimeInMilliSeconds) as "Median"
| table request, "Median" > 3000 | where Median > 3000
```

I want to create an alert that will trigger every time one stat appears

Currently have my trigger set up like this: 
[image]

Then i have an action that it will go to a slack channel i created when triggered.

However i do not ever see it being triggered in my slack despite having results in the Statistics section of my query

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use the Trigger alert when `Number of Results` `is greater than` `0`.

Your trigger alert condition isn't valid. You would use something like `where count > 1` and include a `stats count` at the end of your search expression. This is overly complex though.

It also appears you want to run a search for 7 days worth of data every minute. Depending on the volume, this could be an expensive query. It could be better to look at other options such as summary indexing.